# emptyChangingEventArgs

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm new in asp.net and I created a data context.

I searched a lot but I cant find what does this line mean.

```
 private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
```

Comment: It's just Initializes a new instance of the `PropertyChangingEventArgs` class.

Comment: yes .may u explaine me why it empty the string?

Comment: It's `PropertyName` you can pass your property name over there, See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertychangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so,when it makes it empty indicates that all of the properties have changed?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! You can indicate all properties have changed by using `null` or `string.Empty` for the property name in `PropertyChangedEventArgs`

Comment: Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
```

Here it's indicate all properties have changed by using `null` or `string.Empty` for the property name in `PropertyChangedEventArgs`

This you can find from documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)